# Does there exist a one-to-one function from $\mathbb{N}^5 \mapsto \mathbb{N}^3$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on a coding project and I have a 5-dimensional vector $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{N}^5$ that I need to map (in a **unique** fashion) to RGB colorspace (so, essentially I just want to map $\mathbf{v}$ to some $\mathbf{r} \in $ $\mathbb{N}^3$).

I've been able to find [Cantor's Pairing Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), which was quite useful for a different purpose I had but doesn't seem to be of use here. So, my question does there exist such an injection from $\mathbb{N}^5 \mapsto \mathbb{N}^3$?

Comment: Do you want to know if there exists an injection (yes) , or do you want to know one?

Comment: Note that 'RGB space' isn't usually $\mathbb{N}^3$, it's usually $[0\ldots255]^3$ and unique mapping will depend on how many possible vectors $\mathbf{v}$ you can have and the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Well, both I guess.. But like I said I'm doing something related to coding so I need to know what it is and use it.

Comment: Why not just $(a, b, c, d, e) \mapsto (C(a, b), C(c, d), e)$, where $C$ is Cantor's Pairing Function?

Comment: If you have a pairing function $\Phi:\Bbb N^2\to\Bbb N$, then $G(x,y,z)=\Phi(\Phi(x,y),z)$ is a bijection $\Bbb N^3\to\Bbb N$, and hence $H(x,y,z,v,w)=(G(x,y,z),v,w)$ is a map such as the one you ask for.

Comment: Sure, there are loooots of such injections, one would be $$\mathbb{N}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^3, (a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5) \mapsto (a_1, a_2, 2^{a_3} 3^{a_4} 5^{a_5}).$$

Comment: I suspect you have finite domain and codomain and want a nice map. If that's the case, please [edit] the question to tell us exactly what those sets are.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki.. Yes, I agree.. I was just hoping a could just normalize whatever function I find to 255.. As to your second point, I have well under $(263)^3$ vectors $\mathbf{v}$

Comment: @TheoBendit Ah, thanks so much. That's perfect! I feel silly now

Comment: @InertialObserver No problem. Sometimes a problem just needs fresh eyes.

Comment: @InertialObserver This has very much the feel of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) — even if there are fewer than $256^3$ vectors $\mathbf{v}$ in your domain, mapping them in a _good_ (not just unique) way to $[0,255]^3$ is going to be a very context-dependent problem. More information on what, specifically, you're trying to do will help people give you better answers.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki That's fair. Essentially what I'm doing is I'm taking 5 different basketball players at a time (the ones who are playing) and lumping them into a set and calling it a "unit".  Each player has a unique label in $N$, so the unit has a label in $N^5$. For the visualization I'm doing I want to map this unit in $N^5$ to a specific color in RGB space

Comment: So, you need not just a mapping but a mapping that makes it easy to differentiate between return values — for instance, having one squad map to $\langle 0,0,0\rangle$ and one map to $\langle 0,0,1\rangle$ won't be of too much use in disambiguating them on a screen. Assuming that you're choosing groups of 5 from a team of 12, that gives ${12\choose 5} = 792$ possible teams (ignoring position); since $\sqrt[3]{792}\approx 9$ you'll need 9 shades each of R/G/B, and disambiguating will be a real challenge.

Comment: I think the core question here could be a good fit for the [Cross Validated SE site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization) and would definitely encourage you to ask it there.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, I agree it will be a challenge. Luckily I'll be passing this directly to an ML trainer, so it doesn't need to be too obvious. But yes it would be preferable to make them as distinguishable as possible.

Comment: As I understood you want to work on finite subsets instead of $\mathbb N^5$. So if you have no constraint that close 5-uplets have close colors, then for practical purpose (speed wise) have you considered trying a hashing function ? It is not an injection (as there can be collisions), but almost one provided your initial set cardinal 2/3 or 1/2 smaller than $255^3$.

Comment: @zwim Thanks, and yea I had considered using a hashing function, but I thought that they mapped objects to integers, not 3-plets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:In case you're interested, for $k$ a natural, $|\mathbb N^k|= |\mathbb N | $
Using Schroeder-Bernstein, which states that sets $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality iff there is an injection from $A$ to $B$ and an injection from $B$ to $A$ . You have an obvious injection in one side (e.g.,$n \rightarrow (n,0,...,0)$ ) , and in the
opposite direction : Select different primes $p_1, p_2,..,p_k $ and map $$ (n_1,n_2,..,n_k) \rightarrow p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}..p_k^{n_k} $$

Comment: And just what is the downvote for? My crystal ball is in the shop and my psychic is out of town. Maybe easier to write something instead.

Answer (score 0):

Break up $\mathbb N^5$ into $\mathbb N^2×\mathbb N^2×\mathbb N$. Then use the diagonal slice method to map each $\mathbb N^2$ to $\mathbb N$ and render $\mathbb N^3=\text{mapped }\mathbb N×\text{mapped }\mathbb N×\mathbb N$.